# Why did Argentina invade the Falklands when they did, rather than wait for the pending sale of the UK aircraft carriers to complete first?

Tags: united-kingdom, naval, argentina, falklands-war

At the time of the Argentinian invasion, the UK was in the process of selling its aircraft carrier and reducing its naval capacity. If Argentina had waited a short time, it would have been much harder — if not impossible — for the UK to quickly put a task force together.

So, why didn't Argentina wait? Were there internal political, or other factors that caused Argentina to move when she did?

---

[Background on sale of HMS_Invincible (from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Invincible_%28R05%29)  (see wikipedia for references to news papers reports etc.)

> On 25 February 1982, after several months of negotiations, the
>   Australian government announced that it had agreed to buy Invincible
>   for £175 million as a replacement, under the name HMAS Australia, for
>   the Royal Australian Navy's HMAS Melbourne. The sale was confirmed by
>   the Ministry of Defence.

[Background on decommission plans for HMS_Hermes  (from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hermes_%28R12%29#Falklands_War)  (see wikipedia for references to news papers reports etc.)

> Hermes was due to be decommissioned in 1982 after a 1981 defence
>   review (that would have made the Royal Navy considerably smaller) by
>   the British government, but when the Falklands War broke out, she was
>   made the flagship of the British forces, setting sail for the South
>   Atlantic just three days after the Argentine invasion of the Falkland
>   Islands.

Note at present the UK has no fixed-winged aircraft carriers. If the Falklands was invaded today...

However, the Falklands have a lot more defenses, so they would be a lot harder to invade.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Argentinians belived that the British would not fight to recover the islands if they were taken quickly enough. If that were the case then the capabilities of the British navy weren't really a factor.

Comment: @SteveBird yes, they never considered that the British, after the gutting of their armed forces in the late 1970s and a long period of Labour governments, had the guts or the capability to mount a successful campaign to retake the islands. And they were nearly proven right, powerful forces in the UK government and defense department argued just that, that it would be impossible to succeed and that therefore they shouldn't even try. Thatcher went against them, stating more or less that it's better to try and fail than to never try at all.

Answer (score 14):

They had originally planned the invasion to happen later, but it was rushed forward for internal political reasons. The population was getting restless, and "liberating the Malvinas" was seen by the junta as a good way to bolster support in the light of a faltering economy.
Classic case of using foreign military adventures to distract people from internal economic problems.

Read [The Falklands War by Martin Middlebrook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094JTQE4)  for both the military and political events leading up to (and happening during) the war. ISBN of printed edition 978-1848846364

Comment: You are right, but you can say the same thing about Thatcher. At the time of the Falklands war her popularity was at all all-time low.

Comment: @fdb Yes. The whole episode was quintessentially Bismarkian - nothing better than a foreign war to bolster support for a government. In Britain's case it worked wonderfully. Margaret Thatcher, by calling a 'khaki election' won in 1983 by a landslide.

Answer (score 0):

There were two aircraft carriers used in the Falklands war, HMS Hermes, and HMS Invincible. Both continued in service, I think I am right in saying, for several years after the conflict.

But the Argentine air force was defeated, not so much by the VTO Harriers as by the ship-based missile systems. Given that the Royal Navy was geared up for a potential conflict with the Soviet Union, and policed the entire eastern Atlantic from Greenland to the Cape, as it largely still does, with *inter-alia*, packs of nuclear-powered hunter-killer submarines, it would have been a remarkable thing if it had proven unable to knock over a 17-ship navy in the south Atlantic. The total number of ships used by Britain in the expedition was, I think, over 200.

Indeed had an Argentine victory at any time have appeared remotely possible I believe the United States would have been obliged to become involved in support, as a British defeat in such circumstances would have represented an intolerable blow to NATO morale.

Comment: The only concrete fact in this answer is stated incorrectly: British Harriers shot 20 Argentinian planes in air-to-air combat, and had no losses in air-to-air combat. The rest of the answer are speculations not related to the question and sowing only anti-British bias of the author.

Comment: @Alex I certainly don't mean to express anti-British bias - I am British to the soles of my feet, though never a supporter of Margaret Thatcher. The Harriers did indeed achieve some startling success against the much faster Mirages and others - which astonished many people since Harriers were never designed as aerial combat aircraft, but for infantry-support. Even so it would have been impossible to contain the very sophisticated Argentine air-force without Sea Wolf, Sea Dart, and Rapier anti-aircraft systems.

Comment: @Alex For your further information *Hermes* was retired from the Royal Navy in 1984, two years after the Falklands War, and *Invincible*, twenty-three years later in 2005. I am puzzled as to why you do not consider these 'concrete facts'.

Comment: @WS2 no Mirages were in theater to be shot down by anyone. The Super Etandards were fought mostly by the Harrier force. The missiles of the fleet and ground forces saw relatively little action, certainly far less than the all-missile strategy of the UK military had predicted (which was a good thing as a lot of them were inoperable because of salt water damage, especially the Rapiers).

Comment: @WS2: Everything about "Russians" and "Americans" in your answer is a pure speculation not related to the question.

Comment: @Alex I don't think I even mentioned Russians in my answer!

Comment: @jwenting I've not researched this. I am working entirely on my memory from the time. But I distinctly remember lots of Argentine's high-level interceptor aircraft being shot down with heat-seeking missiles. The remarkable thing about the Harriers was not, as I recall, the numbers they hit, but the fact that such a plane, designed for jungle and marine support could operate on equal terms with much faster jets.

Comment: @jwenting I think, incidentally, that the Rapiers were installed on dry land once they had established the bridgehead at Port St. Carlos.

Comment: @WS2 yes, the surviving ones were. They were however late to arrive, and only some of them worked.

Comment: @jwenting I have just looked up the details of the Argentine air losses, which amounted, in all to 93 aircraft of one kind or another. 27 were captured, 21 destroyed on the ground, and the remaining 45 destroyed in the air. Of those 21 were hit by Sea Harriers (which I will admit is more than I had thought). The remaining 24 were downed by some form of anti-aircraft weaponry, mostly Sea Dart, and Sea Wolf (none of the hits being from carrier-based fire).

Comment: @WS2 yes, and which is a far lower percentage than predicted by UK warplans which insisted on SAMs being the one and only way to fight aircraft...

Comment: @jwenting But I still think it ridiculous that some people continue to assert that Britain almost lost and that Argentina, when it invaded thought it had a serious prospect of winning. The fact is that they did not for a moment think that Britain would take the matter seriously enough to send a force to recover the islands. And Britain would not have done, had not our then Prime Minister seen the opportunity to wrap herself in the national flag, and win the next general election. Britain's was the world's third most powerful navy. Argentina was on a hiding to nothing.

Comment: @WS2: I was commenting on the original version (before you or someone else edited it). In the original version, Soviet Union was mentioned. Sorry for calling it "Russians" but I do not associate "new" countries that liberated themselves from the Russian yoke with Soviet Union:-)

Comment: @Alex You are quite right. I did say that the Royal Navy was geared up for a potential conflict with the Soviet Union, with responsibility for guarding the whole of the eastern Atlantic. Thus it would have been a bit of a turn-up if they had been seen off by Argentina. That was my only point. And it does address what the OP asked. Argentina, when they invaded, did not remotely think that Britain would respond - see my comments *passim*.

Comment: @WS2 Britain certainly stood a very real chance of losing. They were at the end of the longest logistical chain ever in  the history of warfare, they were outnumbered, they were outgunned, and it was not at all certain when they set out with the taskforce that they'd have international support (in fact there were strong voices in the US for sending support to Argentina, which the US were trying to retain and strengthen as an ally in Latin America. What do you think would have happened had they had a few dozen Harpoon missiles and aircraft to launch them...).

Comment: @jwenting Marcel Dassault, head of the French arms manufacturer, is said to have clapped his hands with glee, when their Exocet hit HMS Sheffield. But generally Douglas Hurd, the Foreign Secretary did a good job at keeping Britain's allies, especially the EU countries, on side. Even the Italians backed us. Had America seen its vital interests among the junta of South America, rather than with the democracies of Western Europe, over the matter of some near-uninhabited islands in the south Atlantic, one can only speculate what might have happened! These are the realms of the ridiculous.

Comment: @jwenting Sorry, not Douglas Hurd. It was Francis Pym.

Comment: @jwenting The other thing that assisted a British victory was that although we were greatly outnumbered in ground troops, Argentina's was a conscript army. The latter are notoriously ill disciplined. Whilst conscripts tend to retreat at the first sound of distant gunfire, professionally trained soldiers will dig themselves in. Argentinian farm and factory workers were up against the Parachute Regiment, the Royal Marines, the Guards and the Gurkhas - forces not easily pushed backwards, and undoubtedly far better equipped than they were.